# Do Until loop only returning one section

Tags: vb.net, function, vba, loops

Trying to make a random password generator in VB.NET

So far have got this, but it only returns the first section of what im trying to do

I have 3 inputs for Type of password as checkboxes, in this order:

```
Numeric
Alphabetic
Symbols
```

If i have numeric checked it returns a numeric password, but if i have numeric and alphabetic checked it only returns a numeric password, although if i uncheck numeric and only have alphabetic checked it then returns and alphabetic password

An alphabetic password also has three options:

```
Uppercase
Lowercase
Mixed Case
```

Which when used with alphabetic actually returns the correct password

Here is the code i have so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    C_Numeric.Checked = True
    R_Upper.Checked = True
End Sub

Private Sub B_Generate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles B_Generate.Click
    Dim c_a As Boolean = False
    Dim c_b As Boolean = False
    Dim c_c As Boolean = False
    Dim a As Integer
    If C_Numeric.Checked = True Then
        c_a = True
    ElseIf C_Alphabetic.Checked = True Then
        c_b = True
    ElseIf C_Symbols.Checked = True Then
        c_c = True
    End If
    If R_Lower.Checked = True Then
        a = 1
    ElseIf R_Upper.Checked = True Then
        a = 2
    ElseIf R_Mixed.Checked = True Then
        a = 3
    End If
    If C_Numeric.Checked = True Or C_Alphabetic.Checked = True Or C_Symbols.Checked = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = GenPass(NumericUpDown1.Value, c_a, c_b, c_c, a)
    End If
End Sub

Function GenPass(ByVal Length As Integer, ByVal Num As Boolean, ByVal Alp As Boolean, ByVal Ascii As Boolean, ByVal Complexity As Integer)
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim Pass As String = ""
    Do Until Pass.Length = Length
        Dim a As Integer
        a = rand.Next(1, 3 + 1)
        If a = 1 And Num = True Then
            Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("0"), Asc("9") + 1))
        End If
        If a = 2 And Alp = True Then
            If Complexity = 1 Then
                Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("a"), Asc("z") + 1))
            ElseIf Complexity = 2 Then
                Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("A"), Asc("Z") + 1))
            ElseIf Complexity = 3 Then
                Dim b As Integer
                b = rand.Next(1, 2 + 1)
                If b = 1 Then
                    Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("A"), Asc("Z") + 1))
                ElseIf b = 2 Then
                    Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("a"), Asc("z") + 1))
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If a = 3 And Ascii = True Then
            Dim b As Integer
            b = rand.Next(1, 4 + 1)
            If b = 1 Then
                Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("!"), Asc("/") + 1))
            ElseIf b = 2 Then
                Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc(":"), Asc("@") + 1))
            ElseIf b = 3 Then
                Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("["), Asc("`") + 1))
            ElseIf b = 4 Then
                Pass += ChrW(rand.Next(Asc("{"), Asc("~") + 1))
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Return (Pass)
End Function
```

For Example (Assume Length is 16 for all answers):

Having Numeric and Alphabetic selected with Mixed Case Should return:

```
eVOv3fyTmW7mvH24 CZOXVzeo1EzLu7Al V313p9VLW0Bz7Zfi
```

But instead returns:

```
8343299372194893 7303963979299152 3918539496952829
```

I Have not got a clue why is it not actually returning the desired results

Any help would be appreciated

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of

```
If C_Numeric.Checked = True Then
    c_a = True
ElseIf C_Alphabetic.Checked = True Then
    c_b = True
ElseIf C_Symbols.Checked = True Then
    c_c = True
End If
```

So if `C_Numeric` and `C_Alphabetic` are checked, `c_a` gets `True`, but the line setting `c_b` to `True` won't be hit due to the `ElseIf`.

So, remove the `Else` part.

---

Also, you could simplify this code by writting:

```
c_a = C_Numeric.Checked 
c_b = C_Alphabetic.Checked 
c_c = C_Symbols.Checked
```

instead of the `If` clauses, or better, getting rid of those unnecessary variables by just calling:

```
GenPass(NumericUpDown1.Value, C_Numeric.Checked, C_Alphabetic.Checked, C_Symbols.Checked, a)
```

---

There are a lot more improvements possbile. For example, instead of passing the `Complexity` parameter as `Integer`, create an `Enum`:

```
Enum Complexity
    LowerOnly
    UpperOnly
    Mixed
End Enum

Function GenPass(Length As Integer, Num As Boolean, Alp As Boolean, Ascii As Boolean, Complexity As Complexity)
```

---

If you're using VB 10.0 (introduced with .Net 4.0), you can get rid of the clunky `ByVal` keyword. Also, the [.Net Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in.

---

Some more notes:

If you're checking a boolean value in an `If` clause, there's no need to explicitly write `= True`:

```
If a = 3 And Ascii = True Then
```

could be written as

```
If a = 3 AndAlso Ascii Then
```

Note that `AndAlso` is generally better suited as `And` due to it's short-circut behaviour.

Also, better name your parameter `useAcii` instead of `Acii`. It will make it more clearer.

Comment: Thanks, Stupid mistakes sometimes, and will take your suggestions into account

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the desired result.

```
If C_Numeric.Checked = True Then
    c_a = True
End If
If C_Alphabetic.Checked = True Then
    c_b = True
End If
If C_Symbols.Checked = True Then
    c_c = True
End If
```